# What is the Time Complexity for sorting all elements of ⌈logn⌉ sorted lists of ⌊n/logn⌋ elements each?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose there are ⌈logn⌉ sorted lists of ⌊n/logn⌋ elements each. The time complexity of producing a sorted list of all these elements is: (Hint:Use a heap data structure)

A. O(nloglogn)

B. Θ(nlogn)

C. Ω(nlogn)

D. Ω(n3/2)

My Understanding:

There are logn list each containing n/logn elements then we can apply min heap procedure each of the list 
it can be done in O(n/logn). Now we have logn list which satisfy the min heap property. Now how can i understand it further i am really confused here. Please help me to visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I assume we're sorting into increasing order]

Build a heap of the smallest (ie: first) element of each list, (and for each, along with the value, keep a record of which list it came from at which index). Repeatedly remove the smallest element of this heap, and then insert the next element in the list it came from (if that list hasn't already been consumed). This gives you the sorted list of all the elements.

This heap has [log(n)] elements, so the initial cost of building this heap is O(log(n)), and each remove and insert takes O(log(log n)) time. So overall, the cost of this sort is O(log(n) + nlog(log n)) = O(nloglogn).

Comment: Paul Hankin, Does deletion from heap take O(1) as it is min heap Right ? and For Insertion we insert the element at the end of heap and apply min_heapify() Procedure, There are logn element here therefore it will take O(logn) time, I am confused with O(log(log n)) time. Can you please explain a bit more.
Thanks

Comment: @SanjayVerma you are mistaken about heap operations. Both insert and remove take O(log N) where N is the size of the heap. Here, N = log n, so they both take O(log log n). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_operations

Comment: Okay yes you're right they will take O(log(log n)) but this is min heap we can delete the element in O(1) but to again satisfy the min-heap property we've to apply heapify algo Right and there are logn element then deletion will take log(log n).